# How can I get more snacks?

Tags: castle-clash

To upgrade my super pets, I need Super Pet Snacks, and a lot. For example:

> [image]

Each spawn can give 5 snacks, but obtaining the components required to spawn isn't trivial and limited as well, e.g. can't buy them in shop.

Is there any way besides spawning to get the Snacks directly?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen these cookies enywhere else than the bazaar ($$$) I am afraid. [image]

Comment: Yeah, smart move on the business side: they provide the pets for free, but to make them stronger you have to pay, or wait for really long time. :/

Answer (score 0):

I got 50 Spawning Agents (which can be used to create 25 Pet Snacks) in a "Sign-In Daily and Win" event, which takes place every month or so:

> [image]

So to get snacks, you should just sign in every day to get those bonuses, and have lots of patience. :)